# How to loop an analysis in R while iteratively removing/replacing rows from the original dataset?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have an excel csv file with mixed data that looks similar to the sample dataframe provided below.

Given the following sample data and analysis:

```
#Installing packages
library(cluster)
library(vegan)

size = c(5,300,500,4000,60000,2000)
diet = c('A','A','C','D','C','D')
area = c('Ae','Te','Fo','Ae','Te','Ae')
time = c('Di','No','Di','Cr','Ca','Ca')
distance = c(50,800,60,12000,150000,4200)

DF = data.frame(size,diet,area,time,distance)
row.names(DF) = c('Bird','Rat','Cobra','Dog','Human','Fish')

#Calculate Gower distance dissimilarity matrix for species in "DF" 
DF.diss = daisy(DF, metric = "gower", type = list(logratio = c("size", "distance")))
attributes(DF.diss)

#Performing hierarchical cluster analysis on dissimilarity matrix
DF.Hclust = hclust(DF.diss, method = "average")

#Calculating metric for species community based on hclust tree
treeheight(DF.Hclust)
```

Starting with the all the rows as the example does, how would I go about rerunning the analysis while iteratively removing a row, rerunning the analysis, putting the row back, removing the next row, rerunning the analysis, and so on, until the analysis has been done once for every species removed/replaced.

I am interested in calculating the treeheight metric for the entire community while removing and replacing single species to gauge each of their contributions to overall treeheight.

Since my actual data set has well over 200 species it would be great if there was a way to do this in R without having to prepare over 200 separate csv files where I've removed single species and then running each through the provided analysis. Also is it possible to output each treeheight output/result to a table?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop for this:

```
treeheights <- matrix(-9999, nrow(DF), 1) # make matrix to store answers. 
# I set -9999 as standard value so I can check if everything went alright afterwards. 

for ( i in 1:nrow(DF)) {
DF.LOO <- DF[-i,] # leave one (row) out 
DF.diss.LOO <- daisy(DF.LOO, metric = "gower", type = list(logratio = 
c("size", "distance")))
DF.HC.LOO <- hclust(DF.diss.LOO, method = "average")
treeheights[i,] <- treeheight(DF.HC.LOO)
}
```

This goes through all the rows and always leaves one row out. Hope this helps!

Comment: So I tested it and it works as intended with the sample data. Going to adapt it for the actual larger data set and let you know if all goes well. Thanks a ton! Just a quick Q. Am I correct in assuming that the order in which the metrics appear in the treeheight matrix refers to the metric after removal of the species in the corresponding rownumber in the source dataframe? Like first treeheight is after dog removal, then second is after replacing dog and then rat removal?

Comment: Yes! You are right! The 'i' in DF[-i,]  stands for the iteration that it is currently in. It goes from 1 to the last row. It has the value of the current iteration. So it first removes the first row from the original dataset and in the second iteration, it removes the second row from the original dataset. It does not really place the first row back, it just removes one from the original dataset and saves it as another dataset and does the calculations with that one.